# Hopf-Rinow Theorem tell us: $M$ a Riemannian manifold and every closed and bounded subset of $M$ is compact . Then $M$ is complete.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Hopf-Rinow tells us :$M$ is a Riemannian manifold such that every closed and bounded subset of $M$ is compact , then $M$ is complete.

Many lectures say this can be proved by the general topology. But this puzzles me.

We need to show that every Cauchy sequence converge to some point in $M$.

> idea:$\{x_n\}$ is a cauchy sequence and thus bounded.

1. How could we say $\overline{ \{x_n\}}$ is bounded ,too.
2. $\overline{ \{x_n\}}$ is bounded , then it is compact by hypothesis . How to choose a subesquence of $\{x_n\}$ s.t. it converges, we only know that $\overline{ \{x_n\}}$ is compact and
   $\{x_n\}$  may not be compact.

Comment: For the first question see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322948/show-that-the-closure-of-a-subset-is-bounded-if-the-subset-is-bounded). For the second point note that compactness of a set in a metric space means that every sequence in the set has a limit point in that set. Now $\{x_n\}$ is for sure a sequence in that set (which is here the closure of $\{x_n\}$)

Comment: Thank you so much!